# Invariance of a set under permutations

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, additive-combinatorics

Given a positive integer $n$, let $f$ be a function 
$$
\{1,\ldots,n\}^2 \to \{1,\ldots,n\}.
$$

Then, it is possible that there exists a permutation $\{\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n\}$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ for which
$$
\{ f(\sigma_i,\sigma_{i+1}): i=1,\ldots,n\}=\{1,\ldots,n\},
$$
where $\sigma_{n+1}:=\sigma_1$. (In particular, $n$ and $f$ are fixed)

**(Rough) Question:** Could it be interesting to study the existence of such permutation? Do they have a specific name?

[The problem seems to be vaguely related to Sidon sets: are there any connection?]

Comment: The function $f$ appears to be defined only for one value of $n$?! On the other hand, if it's a family $\{f_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, then it's not clear what such a characterization means, since each member of the family can be defined independently.

Comment: Also, another way of looking at it is: the function is a coloring of the edges of the complete graph $K_n$ with $n$ colors, and we want to know if there's a Hamiltonian cycle that sees all colors. Again, for each $n$, the coloring can be defined independently.

Comment: Your objection is completely correct. The definition of $f$ (or, equivalently, the colouring of edges of $K_n$) could depend on $n$, hence we have a sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\ge 1}$. Anyway, even assuming that this sequence has some "good" proprieties, whatever this may mean, the question is still rough in any case..
_____________________________

To conclude, you can consider $f$ and $n$ as being fixed (I will edit the question in this direction, thanks for the comment)